# SQL reformat/change view of a table, make duplicate content as columns

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask

Good day to all!

So, I honestly search all the web around, but I think i just don't know where to look.

My problem is:
I have a table

```
|some_date   |keyword|position|
-------------------------------
|'2015-09-27'|key1   |10      |
|'2015-10-10'|key1   |15      |
|'2015-09-27'|key2   |5       |
|'2015-10-10'|key2   |0       |
```

and i need to look it like this:

```
|keyword |'2015-09-27'|'2015-10-10'|
-----------------------------------
|key1    |10          |15          |
|key2    |5           |0           |
```

I actually have table-2 too now and use it for visualisation, but i don't like that if i will be store data that way, the table will be ugly looking.

Also, with table-2 I can't get columns names in a easy way, that is a sad thing too.

Any thoughts how can i achive this? Maybe i need two tables with some relations? I completely stuck with this. Architectural decitions will be nice too.

I have over uniq 200 keywords in that table and in table-2 it is over 600 rows with data now, and in date column only 3 uniq date yet. I making app in flask, so if you knew how table-1 can be visualized in html table like table-2 it will be a great help!

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `crosstab()` function from [`tablefunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tablefunc.html) extension.

```
create extension if not exists tablefunc;

select * from crosstab ($ct$
    select keyword, some_date, position
    from some_table
    order by 1, 2
    $ct$)
ct (keyword text, "2015-09-27" int, "2015-10-10" int);

 keyword | 2015-09-27 | 2015-10-10
---------+------------+------------
 key1    |         10 |         15
 key2    |          5 |          0
(2 rows)
```

Comment: I use heroku as platform, so not sure about extensions...Also, is dates are hardcoded in your example? I search for solution where columns with names as dates will be created automaticly

Comment: Yes, using `crosstab()` you should know the number and type of generated columns and give their names. However, you can use the `pivotcode()` function by Eric Minikel described in [Automatically creating pivot table column names in PostgreSQL](http://www.cureffi.org/2013/03/19/automatically-creating-pivot-table-column-names-in-postgresql/).